# adding removing classes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which if a checkbox is selected extra fields appear and when not selected they disappear, the code I used to do this is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#cmntCheck').change(function () {
        if ($('#cmntCheck').is(':checked')) {
            $("#orderOptPanel").addClass('hidden');
            $("#stAddressRow").addClass('hidden');
            $("#cityRow").addClass('hidden');
            $("#stateRow").addClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $("#orderOptPanel").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#stAddressRow").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#cityRow").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#stateRow").removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

but it does not work, what I found works is .toggleClass() but that is not what I am looking for, I Tried .show() and .hide() but it did not work that is why I did it the way I did above. what I want to do is when the check box is selected show the extra fields and when it is not selected not show them. How do I do this?

***[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68qrf13x/)***

Comment: Do you actually have a CSS class called `hidden` with `display: none` or similar?

Comment: Can you make a JSfiddle example?

Comment: @MikeBrant yes I do.

Comment: do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi JSFiddle example added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#cmntCheck` is a `div`, so it can't be checked.  However, you can test the checked state of its input.

You can [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) the display of all elements based on the checked state of the input:

```
$('#cmntCheck input').change(function () {
  $('#orderOptPanel, #stAddressRow, #cityRow, #stateRow').toggle(!this.checked);
}).change();
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hvhowabL/)

Comment: `!this.checked` but this is the most concise way of writing it

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
    $('#cmntCheck').change(function () {
        var isChecked = $('#cmntCheck').is(':checked')

        $("#orderOptPanel").toggle(!isChecked);
        $("#stAddressRow").toggle(!isChecked);
        $("#cityRow").toggle(!isChecked);
        $("#stateRow").toggle(!isChecked);

    });
});
```

You can use `toggle` (which accepts a bool) to set the style attribute instead of classes. Not sure why you're firing the change event after the change handler though?

Answer (score 2):

There is no value behind adding a class called **hidden** if you only need to show / hide your controls. Just call Show and Hide functions. The cmntCheck here is your checkbox not your DIV

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#cmntCheck").change(function () {

        var checked = $('#cmntCheck').is(':checked');
        if (checked) {
                 {
                    $("#orderOptPanel").hide();
                    $("#stAddressRow").hide();
                    $("#cityRow").hide();
                    $("#stateRow").hide();
                } else {
                    $("#orderOptPanel").show();
                    $("#stAddressRow").show();
                    $("#cityRow").show();
                    $("#stateRow").show();
                }
            })
        }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but with .show() when the check box is selected other wise .hide(), but it only hides it and when I select the box nothing shows

Comment: Just make sure the function is called again :/ I've updated the answer. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work, see my updated question, as well as the jsfiddle example provided.

Comment: I just realized that your container is a DIV not Check box. so Rick got it first ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the css class :

```
.hidden
{
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wd1z0zmg/4/

Or the best way to do it in minified way :

```
$('#cmntCheck').change(function () {
       $('#cmntCheck').is(':checked') ? $("#orderOptPanel, #stAddressRow,#cityRow,#stateRow").hide() : $("#orderOptPanel,#stAddressRow,#cityRow,#stateRow").show();          
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wd1z0zmg/5/